# Connection to channel with SSL enabled gives error about CipherSpec not being specified but it was

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ server with a developer license (https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/) and followed the tutorial from here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-windows/.

So what I have now is:

- IBM MQ Manager
- One *Queue Manager* (QM1)
- 4 Queues (one dead letter queue and 3 dev queues DEV.QUEUE.x) all local
- 2 Channels (one admin and one 'normal' server connection channel)

I enabled SSL on the QM1 queue manager:

[![SSL Settings for QM1][1]][1]

and I also created a personal certificate:
[![Key management][2]][2]

EDIT: I connected with username/password instead of using an SSL certificate. I have fixed this but now I cannot connect either.

I also set the SSL ChiperSpec for the channel to ANY.

`amqsputc dev.queue.1 QM1` now gives me:

`MQCONNX ended with reason code 2058`

Which (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=arc-2058-080a-rc2058-mqrc-q-mgr-name-error) says that the que manager name is wrong. But as far as I can see QM1 is the corecct name.

EDIT: When connecting with the `amqssslc` tool with the following syntax I am getting this:

```
amqssslc -l ibmwebspheremq -k C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key  -c DEV.APP.SVRCONN -x DEV.APP.SVRCONN -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 -m QM1

Sample AMQSSSLC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1
Using the server connection channel DEV.APP.SVRCONN
on connection name DEV.APP.SVRCONN.
Using SSL CipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Using SSL key repository stem C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key
Certificate Label: ibmwebspheremq
No OCSP configuration specified.
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2538
```

Comment: My images are gone. Trying to fix that

Comment: You should ask a new question.   The original question was answered.

Comment: This question no longer matches the title and the answer refers to your error message which has been deleted. What us going on with this question?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message you have shown us says, your channel definition for `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` has not put a value in the `SSLCIPH` attribute.

If this is missing at the queue manager end, use the following MQSC command to rectify:-

```
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(ANY)
```

or alternatively put the same value in the `SSLCIPH` attribute that you are using for the client application.

If this is missing at the client application end, because you can see that there is a value in the `SSLCIPH` attribute on the `SVRCONN` already, change your client application to also use the same cipherspec.

If you are unsure how to, please update your question with the `SVRCONN` definition and details about your client application for more help.